# Many to many relationship: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 2 entities with a many to many relationship.
User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
end
```

And Conversation

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

I have an array of users, how can I select conversations between this users?

I'm currently using `find_by_sql` and a large sql query with JOIN operators, but I think this isn't a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to relate they before create an object and make the join table on your migrations.

Step by step, it will be some like this:
First you do the right, relate your models (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association there is all you need).
Then create a migration like:

```
class CreateConversationUserJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :conversations_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :conversation
      t.references :user
    end
  end
end
```

Now run `rake db:migrate` and ready.

Now there are an examples to relate those models in your controller :

```
@user.conversations << @my_conversation
```

If you go to `rails console` you will check your user conversations with some like :

```
$ User.find(1).conversations
```

If my memory is good, that is all.

Good luck!

Comment: Of course, I created migration for join table. And i know how to find conversation for a user. But I want select coversation for set of users